# Stacking text and images on top of each other

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get my text on top of these three logo/icons. 
I want them to be centered as well. I've tried inline-block, centering text but i might just be doing too much?

html:

```
    <div class= "sign-up">
        <a>Or Sign Up Using</a>
    </div>

    <div class= "sociallogo">
        <div class="socialcontainer">
            <img src="img/facebook.png">
        </div>
        <div class="socialcontainer">
            <img src="img/twitter.png">
        </div>
        <div class="socialcontainer">
            <img src="img/google.png">
        </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.sign-up {
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #777777;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.sociallogo {
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    clear: both;
}

.socialcontainer {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Edit: Sorry - I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @JerryD that is an awful edit, you only made it worse. Made an external link to an image and changed the code snippet to code blocks. Voted for rejection.

Comment: Do not add stuff like "RESOLVED" etc. to either title or text, they way here is to accept the answer that helped you the most.

Comment: Yes, @LGSon is correct. This will help any future visitors to the question. Just find the answer, and by the upvote/downvote button there is the check mark to accept.

Comment: @MarkBaijens I'm sorry. I tried to reformat the code, and put descriptions for the image links, but by the time I submitted it, it had already been changed to have a snippet and in-body images.

Comment: thanks all! it's my first time using it so i didn't know

Comment: @bubblegum All good, welcome to Stack Overflow! Glad my answer helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `display` of `sociallogo` to `block` and changed the `text-align` of the classes to get this result:
[image]

```
 <div class= "sign-up">
        <a>Or Sign Up Using</a>
    </div>

    <div class= "sociallogo">
        <div class="socialcontainer">
            <img src="img/facebook.png">
        </div>
        <div class="socialcontainer">
            <img src="img/twitter.png">
        </div>
        <div class="socialcontainer">
            <img src="img/google.png">
        </div>
    </div>
<style>
.sign-up {
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #777777;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.sociallogo {
    text-align: center
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 5px;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}

.socialcontainer {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `.sign-up` and `.sociallogo` `block` rather than `inline-block`.

Remove `float: left` from `.sign-up`.

Add `text-align: center` to `.sociallogo`.

```css
.sign-up {
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #777777;
  text-align: center;
}

.sociallogo {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.socialcontainer {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sign-up">
  <a>Or Sign Up Using</a>
</div>

<div class="sociallogo">
  <div class="socialcontainer">
    <img src="img/facebook.png">
  </div>
  <div class="socialcontainer">
    <img src="img/twitter.png">
  </div>
  <div class="socialcontainer">
    <img src="img/google.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I quite like using `display: flex` for this kind of thing, really useful for positioning and I think you'll find it really easy to use.

You should use `display: flex` on the container along with `flex-direction` (can be `row` or `column`), but i think you want column here in order to stack them.

And adding `align-items: center` will centre everything horizontally for you.

I've simplified your code below for you:

```css
.sign-up {
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #777777;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.sociallogo img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sign-up">
  <a>Or Sign Up Using</a>
  <div class="sociallogo">
    <img src="img/facebook.png">
    <img src="img/twitter.png">
    <img src="img/google.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `width: 100%` on both containers, this should solve the problem.

Afther that u can use `Transform` and `margin` to center the images.

```css
.sign-up {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #777777;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.sociallogo {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
}

.socialcontainer {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sign-up">
  <a>Or Sign Up Using</a>
</div>

<div class="sociallogo">
  <div class="socialcontainer">
    <img src="img/facebook.png">
  </div>
  <div class="socialcontainer">
    <img src="img/twitter.png">
  </div>
  <div class="socialcontainer">
    <img src="img/google.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

Remove `float: left;` from `.sign-up`

and add `vertical-align: middle;` to both `.sign-up` and `.sociallogo` divs